# MySQL java IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, indexoutofboundsexception, dao

I have a problem with showing the contents of my DB and I am having this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
```

Can someone help me fix this? I have another query that works in my JSP page but this particular query seems to have the exception:

```
select epi.firstName, epi.lastName, esi.license
from `employee-personal-information` epi
join`employee-safeguard-information` esi
    on epi.employeeID = esi.employeeID 
join oic oic
    on esi.employeeID = oic.oicID;
```

This is my DAO code:

```
public ArrayList<Employee> viewOIC() {
    ArrayList<Employee> newEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    try {
        DBConnectionFactory myFactory = DBConnectionFactory.getInstance();
        Connection conn = myFactory.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select epi.firstName, epi.lastName, esi.license\n" + "from `employee-personal-information` epi join`employee-safeguard-information` esi on epi.employeeID = esi.employeeID\n" + "  join oic oic on esi.employeeID = oic.oicID\n" + ";");



        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            Employee tempRI = new Employee();
            tempRI.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
            tempRI.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
            tempRI.setLicense(rs.getString("license"));
            newEmployee.add(tempRI);

        }
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
        return newEmployee;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EmployeeDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please help me fix this. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

My JSP Code:

```
                <% EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
                            ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = employeeDAO.viewEmployee();%>
                <div class="form-bottom">
                    <form action="addTicket" method="post" class="complaint-form">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            Involved Guard:
                            <select name="form-guardInvolved" id="form-guardInvolved" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
                                <% for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++) {%>
                                <option value="<%=employeeDAO.viewEmployee().get(i).getFirstName() + " "%>
                                <%=employeeDAO.viewEmployee().get(i).getLastName()%>"> <%=employeeDAO.viewEmployee().get(i).getFirstName() + " "%>
                                <%=employeeDAO.viewEmployee().get(i).getLastName()%> </option>
                                <% }%>
                            </select>
                            <p> </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                             Reported By:
                            <select name="form-reportedBy" id="form-reportedBy" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
                                <% for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++) {%>
                                <option value="<%=employeeDAO.viewOIC().get(i).getFirstName() + " "%>
                                <%=employeeDAO.viewOIC().get(i).getLastName()%>"> <%=employeeDAO.viewOIC().get(i).getFirstName() + " "%>
                                <%=employeeDAO.viewOIC().get(i).getLastName()%> </option>
                                <% }%>
                            </select>
                            <p> </p>
                        </div>
```

The first part works but the error is in the second part.

Comment: Please include the exception stacktrace.

Comment: I don't see what could possibly throw an IOOB exception in the posted code..

Comment: I feel like the problem is most likely occurring in the class that calls viewOIC(). You may want to add that code as well.

Comment: Mark Rotteveel - I have posted the stacktrace
Jeutnarg - what do you mean by that? my JSP Code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your for loops to for (int i = 0; i < (employeeList.size()-1); i++) ?

Comment: I tried it just now but its still the same error. I also tried int i = -1 and i = 1 but it does not work. I think the issue here is the query itself but i dont get it because I use the same format compared to my first query

Comment: Its working now. I have made a small mistake. I did not put the arraylist for the oic. Thank you!